# Download from Amazon S3 results in "fopen(): failed to open stream: Operation now in progress"

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Occasionally I receive `fopen(...s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/...): failed to open stream: Operation now in progress` when trying to download files from some third-party S3 bucket.

```php
if (! $this->storeStream($path, fopen($url, 'r'))) {
    throw new DownloadException(
        "Unable to download [$url] to [{$path}]"
    );
}
```

Is there a problem with my use of `fopen()` or does this error originate from S3?

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220125/what-does-the-error-message-operation-now-in-progress-mean

Comment: This is a remote file on another server (Amazon S3) I do not control.

Comment: And perhapps, its being written or read from by another context that you arn't in control of.

Comment: I don't know anything about PHP, but if the file is not public you will not be able read it in this way. Also are you sure you can open a file that is not local on your computer using this way?

Comment: As I already wrote in the post this error only occurs occasionally (but enough to be an annoyance and cause troubles on my end). Most of the files download just fine. I suspect this is not a problem with S3 but how PHP handles streams.